# Can't connect to WiFi network

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Did a software update on Ubuntu and now I can't connect to WiFi as there is no option for Wireless network available.

- The output to my `lshw -C network` is

  ```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
     description: Network controller
     product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
     version: 1a
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:fea00000-fea03fff
  ```
- The kernel version as reported by `uname -r` is:

  ```
  6.2.0-26-generic
  ```

Also I went through many tutorials online and tried installing the `linux-modules-extra` but to no avail.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: I am facing same issue. My kernel upgraded from 5.19.0-32 to 6.2.0-31 and wifi is broken. Tried install linux-modules-extra (and it is already installed) and still no success. And the problem is I don't have ethernet cable, only wifi. I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation today.

What worked for me is that I removed CMOS from the motherboard and connected it back.